# Can I use JBox2D on server with Box2D on libGDX on client?

Tags: libgdx, physics, box2d, client-server

I want to use Box2D for my turn-based game, made with libGDX. The client is supposed to do some prediction of physics after his input and I want to correct these calculations with server-side calculations afterwards.
As I do not want to run an entire libGDX project on my server (because there will be parallel games and a single game per GameRoom is not necessary), I thought about running JBox2D on the server and send the final calculations for correction purposes to my two clients.

- Can I e.g. step 10 seconds ahead at once with my server-side physics and send the results to my client right away? I don't need small steps, because the server won't render them anyways
- Will these results mostly match with the client results of the built-in libgdx box2d version? I will here use smaller steps, so the client can render the changes easily.

Thanks in advance!